# XNA application can't find the Application Files folder

Tags: file, xna, publishing

I wanted to show my game to a friend so I published it and stored the files on a memory stick. However, when I attempted to run it on his computer I received this error

"Cannot download the application.The application is missing required files. Contact application vendor for assistance"

Publication process produced "setup.exe" and "Shooter.application"

This is the error summary:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of F:\Shooter.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file:///F:/Application Files/Shooter_1_0_0_0/Shooter.exe.manifest did not succeed.
    + Could not find a part of the path 'F:\Application Files\Shooter_1_0_0_0\Shooter.exe.manifest'.
    + Could not find a part of the path 'F:\Application Files\Shooter_1_0_0_0\Shooter.exe.manifest'.
    + Could not find a part of the path 'F:\Application Files\Shooter_1_0_0_0\Shooter.exe.manifest'.
```

Comment: Does the file F:\Application Files\Shooter_1_0_0_0\Shooter.exe.manifest exist?